# Github Actions run failed with error Cannot find module 'ui-repo' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: node.js, typescript, github-actions, monorepo

I am creating GitHub Actions workflows for my monorepo on GitHub but I am getting an error at TypeScript check job by running `tsc --noEmit`, that error is:

> error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ui-repo' or its corresponding
> type declarations.

It still passed when I testing on my local development but failed on GitHub workflows. What am I missing and how can I solve this error?

Below are the configuration files for my `ui-repo` used to share with other repository in my monorepo system.

tsconfig.json of `ui-repo`:

```
{
   "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
   "display": "Default",
   "compilerOptions": {
      "composite": false,
      "declaration": true,
      "declarationMap": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
      "inlineSources": false,
      "isolatedModules": true,
      "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
      "module": "ESNext",
      "target": "ESNext",
      "jsx": "react-jsx",
      "lib": ["ESNext", "DOM"],
      "noUnusedLocals": false,
      "noUnusedParameters": false,
      "preserveWatchOutput": true,
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "strict": true,
      "strictNullChecks": true,
      "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
      "allowJs": true,
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
      "downlevelIteration": true,
      "noEmit": true,
      "baseUrl": "."
   },
   "include": ["."],
   "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "build"]
}
```

package.json of `ui-repo`:

```
{
   "name": "ui-repo",
   "version": "2.0.0",
   "description": "UI Repository",
   "sideEffects": false,
   "exports": {
      ".": {
         "require": "./dist/index.js",
         "import": "./dist/index.mjs",
         "types": "./dist/index.d.mts",
         "default": "./dist/index.mjs"
      },
      "./*": {
         "require": "./dist/*.js",
         "import": "./dist/*.mjs",
         "types": "./dist/*.d.mts",
         "default": "./dist/*.mjs"
      }
   },
   ...etc...
}
```

TypeScript: v5.2.2

Node.js Runtime: 18.18.2